# Error while upgrading 2.2.4 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2.4, magento2.3.3

Getting below error

> Notice: Undefined index: column in
>   /var/www/html/TTM/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php
>   on line 196

Comment: When are you getting this error? During `setup:upgrade`?

Comment: @Marisa, yes during the setup upgrade and also facing SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: Can't write duplicate key in table error, I am not sure why this kind of error getting with my existing DB.